# Fiware Orion contextbroker installation error in RHEL 7.2: package does not exist

Tags: yum, fiware, fiware-orion, rhel7

When I am trying to install the Fiware Orion Contextbroker on RHEL 7.2 using the instructions on the following link : https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/yum/index.html

I am successfully able to download the broker from the public repository. However, upon running `sudo yum install contextBroker` I get the following error :

> No package contextBroker available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Try `yum clean all` before `yum install contextBroker` and see if it works. By the way, you are using the configuration suggested at the link, right?

Comment: Is this the same described at https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3183? In that case, if the issue is solved, I'd suggest you self-answer in order to explain what the cause was, for the help of the users. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue can be solved by following the steps on the updated guide provided by Fiware. The issue was solved on GitHub.  https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/pull/3184